# Sending emails from MVC application hosted in Azure not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, smtp, smtpclient

Ive gone through many posts, but none seem to work.

I have an MVC application hosted in Azure as an app service and sending of mails is not working. It works on my local.

I have my SMTP details stored in my Web.Config:

### Web.Config

```
 <appSettings>
    <!--To Send Mail-->
    <add key="MailServerSMTP" value="mail.appname.com" />
    <add key="MailServerSMTP_UserName" value="alerts@appname.com" />
    <add key="MailServerSMTP_Password" value="Password" />
  </appSettings>
```

Below is my sending function:

### Email sending function

```
public void SendMessage(string subject, string messageBody, string fromAddress, string toAddress, string ccAddress, string sFileName, string sFileName2)
        {

            try
            {

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

                //Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate ()
                //{
                    //Set the sender's address
                    message.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

                    //Allow multiple "To" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
                    if ((toAddress.Trim().Length > 0))
                    {
                        foreach (string addr in toAddress.Split(';'))
                        {
                            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
                        }
                    }

                    //Allow multiple "Cc" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
                    if ((ccAddress.Trim().Length > 0))
                    {
                        foreach (string addr in ccAddress.Split(';'))
                        {
                            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
                        }
                    }

                    //Set the subject and message body text
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFileName))
                    {
                        Attachment obAttachement = new Attachment(sFileName);
                        message.Attachments.Add(obAttachement);
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFileName2))
                    {
                        Attachment obAttachement = new Attachment(sFileName2);
                        message.Attachments.Add(obAttachement);
                    }

                    message.Subject = subject;
                    message.Body = messageBody;
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                    path = path.Replace("bin\\Debug\\", "Content\\img");

                    //if (path.Substring(path.Length - 6) != "Images")
                    //{
                    //    path = path + "Images";
                    //}

                    if (path.GetLast(6) != "Content\\img")
                    {
                        path = path + "Content\\img";
                    }

                    Attachment ImageAttachment = new Attachment(path + "\\SystemicLogic_Transparent.png");

                    // Set the ContentId of the attachment, used in body HTML
                    ImageAttachment.ContentId = "SystemicLogic_Transparent.png";

                    // Add an image as file attachment
                    message.Attachments.Add(ImageAttachment);

                    message.Body = messageBody;



                    //Set the SMTP server to be used to send the message
                    //client.Host = "smtp.jumpstartcom.co.za"
                    string sSMTP_Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerSMTP_UserName"].ToString();
                    string sSMTP_Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerSMTP_Password"].ToString();
                    string appname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerSMTP"];

                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sSMTP_Username, sSMTP_Password);

                    client.Host = appname;
                    client.Port = 587;
                //client.EnableSsl = true;

                //Send the e-mail message
                //client.SendAsync(message, null);
                client.Send(message);
                //});

                //T1.Start();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

I have tried enabling SSL and using port 25. I have tried setting the port to 465 and 587 and emails are not coming through though.

Is there a specific port that needs to be used, or something I am doing wrong ?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: is this on a VM or is it hosted on app service ?? where is your smtp server?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, it is on an app service, I have updated my post. The SMTP server is my clients SMTP details, so I honestly dont know.

Comment: are you able to connect to the smtp server ?. if not try some other ports. or it could be that your smtp server is not accepting call from azure or outside their network. other options are to use mail relay services like sendgrid.

Comment: Sending of emails from these SMTP details does work when running from my local, so I am able to connect to the SMTP server. Ill do some research on what ports I can use, hopefully it works. Thanks